# Accessing Microphone and Camera Live Raw Data on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession, audioqueue, remoteio

I need to access live raw data from camera and microphone on iPhone. I was searching for a few days, using "Remote IO" and "Audio Queue" were suggested for audio and AVCaptureSession for video. Since I couldn't find a way to pull raw audio information from AVCatpureSession I was wondering if it's possible to do both with AVCaptureSession or should I use two different approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pull audio from an AVCaptureSession by setting up a AVCaptureAudioDataOutput and adding it to your capture session. You can control the format of the audio data by setting the audioSettings property on the AVCaptureAudioDataOutput object.

You can find some Apple sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html).